# How to enforce a restriction of using Instant.now() or new Date() in any Java Test Methods?

Tags: java, java-time, archunit

Want to enforce a restriction of using Instant.now() or new Date() in any Java Method.
Below is the sample class

```java
class Demo {

    void methodOne() {
        Date date = new Date();
        // ...
    }

    void methodTwo() {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following simple `ArchRule` unconditionally forbids calling these methods:

```java
    @ArchTest
    ArchRule no_direct_date_or_instant_instantiation =
        com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition
            .noClasses()
            .should().callConstructor(Date.class)
            .orShould().callMethod(Instant.class, "now");
```

For your `Demo` class, this gives:

> `java.lang.AssertionError`: Architecture Violation [Priority: MEDIUM] - Rule 'no classes should call constructor Date.() or should call method Instant.now()' was violated (2 times):
> Method <`Demo.methodOne()`> calls constructor <`java.util.Date.<init>()`> in (SO77127672.java:29)
> Method <`Demo.methodTwo()`> calls method <`java.time.Instant.now()`> in (SO77127672.java:34)

Comment: Given Solution is not checking the Violation inside a Method (as I mentioned in question). It is only checking violation on the class level Variables. 
I want to restrict the usage inside a method of a class

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should work in the way you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it didn't work as expected .
it is working for the class level variables i.e 

Class Demo {
Date dt = new Date(); // it is marked as violation by ArchUnit

void doSomething(){
Instant it = Instant.ow(); // it is not marked as violation by test case
}

}

Comment: I've added the failure you should get to my answer.